# Converting array of json table objects

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have response from one API that comes as array of json table objects.

I'm trying to deserialize it but it always returns null.

Json format:

```
        {
            "tables": [
                {
                "name": "PrimaryResult",
                "columns": [
                    {
                    "name": "data1",
                    "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                    "name": "data2",
                    "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                    "name": "data3",
                    "type": "string"
                    }
                ],
                "rows": [
                    [
                    "9e94c46f-81b5-4186-8f25-42db447c94bb",
                    "value1",
                    "value2"
                    ],
                    [
                    "kds73j39dsd9sdsd0dd08d6d3dfdf443f44f4",
                    "value2",
                    "value3"
                    ]
                ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

My classes:

```
        class DataConvert
        {
            public Data[] data { get; set; }
        }

        public class Data
        {
            public string data1 { get; set; }
            public string daat2 { get; set; }
            public string data3 { get; set; }
        }

        DataConvert data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataConvert>(json);
```

Should the build my object somewhat differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be like

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Table[] tables { get; set; }
}

public class Table
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Column[] columns { get; set; }
    public string[][] rows { get; set; }
}

public class Column
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

just copy your JSON string , goto visual studio Edit -> Past Special -> and select Past JSON as classes

and your object will be

```
 Rootobject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Column
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Table
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Column> columns { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> rows { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Table> tables { get; set; }
}
```

To make your life easyer just use http://json2csharp.com/ to generate c# classes from json

Comment: visual studio can already do this for you without needing to go to a website. In visual studio go to "Edit" -> "Paste special" => "Parse JSON as classes"

Comment: Got it working as T. Giri and you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: @fly3rbug thats neat, i will surely use that in the future!